# Understanding the use of && in a react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to understand this functional component in react.
I know Post accepts two parameters post and excerpt. 2 tenary operators
were used

Here is the render code from a component that uses post.

```
        const renderPosts = () => {
            if (loading) return <p>Loading posts...</p>
            if (hasErrors) return <p>Unable to display posts.</p>

            return posts.map(post => <Post key={post.id} post={post} excerpt />)
        }
```

I don't understand what (excerpt &&) is doing together with the Link below.
Can you explain this to me? Also passing excerpt from the map helper above,
what does that imply? It has no value.

```
        export const Post = ({ post, excerpt }) => (
          <article className={excerpt ? 'post-excerpt' : 'post'}>
            <h2>{post.title}</h2>
            <p>{excerpt ? post.body.substring(0, 100) : post.body}</p>

            {excerpt && (
              <Link to={`/posts/${post.id}`} className="button">
                View Post
              </Link>
            )}
          </article>
        )
```

Comment: Try not to ask multiple questions in a single question.  SO is designed for "one question, one answer" - you can only mark one answer as "correct".  There's nothing wrong with posting multiple fine-grained questions to SO, you can even cross reference the questions if you want to avoid having to post all the details multiple times. Posting single questions helps you get your answers quicker, helps others more easily answer the parts of your question that they understand and keeps answers easier to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You posted this question with `reactjs` as the only tag, indicating you think this is a `react` thing, but fundamentally your question is about a `javascript` thing: "[Short circuit conditionals](https://codeburst.io/javascript-short-circuit-conditionals-bbc13ac3e9eb)".

From the code you posted:

```
excerpt && <Link ...>
```

is expressing

```
if excerpt 
  then return <Link ...> 
  else return undefined
```

So if `excerpt` evaluates "falsy", nothing will be displayed (because [React ignores undefined or null](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator)), but if `excerpt` is "truthy" then the link will be displayed.

---

EDIT:

I just noticed you had a second question in there:

> Also passing excerpt from the map helper above, what does that imply? It has no value.

Omitting the value of an attribute causes JSX to treat it as true.  See this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37829171/924597) elsewhere.

So that bit of code is expressing that it wants the `Post` component to always add the Link.

Note your second question is actually very react-specific, given that React goes out of its way to define these "empty" attributes as "truthy", when the default behaviour of HTML treats them as "falsy" - see this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23752239/924597) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

if excerpt is true (truthy) the Link will be displayed. The && operator executes once the condition is met.

Comment: So does it imply that if excerpt  was not passed as part of the Post prop the link will not show right?

Comment: @user2320476 Yes. And passing only the property name is the same as `excerpt={true}`.

Comment: yes it implies if excerpt is undefined or null the Link won't show

Answer (score 0):

At Post component (below one) && operator will be true if both conditions are true that means excerpt should exist then only Link will work.
Second, passing the excerpt through the map will give the value for different post and excerpt has value you have passed it as an argument in Post component.

Answer (score 0):

> **I don't understand what (excerpt &&) is doing together with the Link below. 
> Can you explain this to me?**

It is called [Conditional Rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) in `react`, a very powerful concept. 
It enables you to render components depending on the state of your application.

```js
// In JavaScript
true && expression === expression 

false && expression === false.

// Within your code
// if excerpt === true
{excerpt && (<Link>...</Link>)} === (<Link>...</Link>) // Component is rendered

// if excerpt === false
{excerpt && (<Link>...</Link>)} === false  // Component isn't be rendered
```

Based on the above, you should now understand why `excerpt` is passed to every `Post`, `excerpt` must be a `boolean` in this implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Have a read of [Logical_Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators).

> **Operator:** Logical AND (`&&`)
> **Syntax:** `expr1 && expr2`
> **Description:** If `expr1` can be converted to `true`, returns `expr2`; else, returns `expr1`.

And then take a look at the [Inline If with Logical && Operator](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator) section on the react docs conditional-rendering page.

```
function Mailbox(props) {
  const unreadMessages = props.unreadMessages;
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello!</h1>
      {unreadMessages.length > 0 &&
        <h2>
          You have {unreadMessages.length} unread messages.
        </h2>
      }
    </div>
  );
}

const messages = ['React', 'Re: React', 'Re:Re: React'];
ReactDOM.render(
  <Mailbox unreadMessages={messages} />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

> It works because in JavaScript, `true && expression` always evaluates to `expression`, and `false && expression` always evaluates to `false`.
>
> Therefore, if the condition is `true`, the element right after `&&` will appear in the output. If it is `false`, React will ignore and skip it.